# Ploting a list of coordinates in different plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have that list of points with 4 coordinates.

```
sols = {{x1 -> -0.1465958058813781`, y1 -> -0.6972834336845714`, 
 x2 -> -0.6972834336845712`, y2 -> -0.14659580588137808`}, {x1 -> 0.6972834336845714`, 
 y1 -> -0.14659580588137813`, x2 -> 0.14659580588137816`, 
 y2 -> -0.6972834336845712`}, {x1 -> 0.14659580588137816`, 
 y1 -> 0.6972834336845714`, x2 -> 0.6972834336845712`, 
 y2 -> 0.14659580588137808`}}
```

I would like  to plot the dots, with the coordinates $x_1 , y_1$ in one plot, and $x_2,y_2$ in another plot. How can I do it ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
sols1 = {x1, y1} /. sols;
sols2 = {x2, y2} /. sols;

ListPlot[sols1]
ListPlot[sols2]
```

or a one line solution for fun:

```
ListPlot /@ (sols[[;; , #, 2]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}})
```

EDIT: 
To plot each point of a different colour and match the colours of the two plots, here's the fastest solution:

```
sols1 = {{x1, y1}} /. sols;
sols2 = {{x2, y2}} /. sols;

ListPlot[sols1]
ListPlot[sols2]
```

If you want to choose a color scheme for your points (e.g. AvocadoColours), see code below:

```
colours = ColorData["AvocadoColors"][[4]] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/(Length@sols1 - 1)]

ListPlot[sols1, PlotStyle -> colours]
ListPlot[sols2, PlotStyle -> colours]
```

Comment: Thx ! Is there a way to plot each point with a different color, so that it is easy to connect each $x_1,y_1$ to its $x_2,y_2$ ?

Comment: Sure, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListPlot[List /@ #, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
 Transpose[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. sols]
```

[image]